# index 0 is out of bounds for axis 0 with size 0?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

def top_n_songs(data, n, min_play_counts=100):

```
recommendations = data[data['play_freq'] > min_play_counts]

recommendations = recommendations.sort_values(by='avg_count', ascending=False)

return recommendations.index[:n]
```

```
res = list(top_n_songs(final_play, 10, 100))

list_of_songs = []
for i in res:
    list_of_songs.append(df_final[df_final['song_id']== str(i) ]['title'].unique()[0])
list_of_songs
```

Error message

```
IndexError                                Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-52-7c7c6897126b> in <module>
      4 list_of_songs = []
      5 for i in res:
----> 6     list_of_songs.append(df_final[df_final['song_id']== str(i) ]['title'].unique()[0])
      7 list_of_songs

IndexError: index 0 is out of bounds for axis 0 with size 0
```

I am a beginner, tried my level best can you give me a hand?

Comment: Can you provide an extract of your dataframe ? `df_final.head()`
And the code of `top_n_songs()`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If `str(i) == song_id` doesn't match anything in `df_final`, the array returned by `.unique()` will be empty, causing an IndexError. Make sure to check that first, before attempting to access it with the subscript (`[0]`).

Comment: thank you for your help its int not str i got the answer.

Answer (score 0):

I am not really sure about it but if you remove that last `[0]`
from `line 6`, I think it will solve your error.

```
list_of_songs.append(df_final[df_final['song_id']== str(i) ]['title'].unique())
```

Comment: yes, i tried it but returned a empty array